# For $ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}<i \leq \frac{ n(n+1)}{2} $, why is $\text{round}(\sqrt{2i})=n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was doing Problem 67 of Project Euler, which involves number triangle which has similar structure to Pascal's triangle (the nth row contains n numbers). While thinking of a way to represent the triangle as a single list, I realized that the number of elements in a triangle of height n was $1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2$, which must mean that the last number of any row n must be the $(n(n+1)/2)^{th}$ number in the triangle. More generally, we have that for any index $i$ starting at 1, $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} < i \leq  \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ where $n$ is the row that contains the $i^{th}$ number of the triangle. From here, I figured that taking the square root of $2i$ and rounding it would give something close to $n$, and indeed rounding the square root of $2i$ results in the pattern $1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5$, etc. So far, I have not been able to prove this result to myself, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Since $i$ is an integer, $$n(n-1) < 2i \leqslant n(n+1) \iff n^2 - n + \tfrac{1}{4} < 2i < n^2 + n + \tfrac{1}{4} \iff \bigl(n - \tfrac{1}{2}\bigr)^2 < 2i < \bigl(n +\tfrac{1}{2}\bigr)^2 \iff n-\tfrac{1}{2} < \sqrt{2i} < n +\tfrac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Das it mane.

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nevermind, I just meant "that's good", thanks!

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{(n-1)^2}2<\frac{n(n-1)}2<\frac{n^2}2<\frac{n(n+1)}2<\frac{(n+1)^2}2$$

We also know that

$$\frac{n(n-1)}2<i<\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

On finding differences, we realise that $i$ will always be closer to $\frac{n^2}2$ than $\frac{(n-1)^2}2$ or $\frac{(n+1)^2}2$

Hence $i=round(\sqrt{2i})$

Comment: This tells me that the square root of $2i$ is approximately $n$, which gives an intuitive understanding (that I already have) of why this true. However, I'm not sure this explicitly proves that the square root of $2i$ can never round to $n-1$ or $n+1$?

Comment: @SimonZhu I don't know. In fact, I thought it could actually round off to $n+1$ or $n-1$ for large $i$.

Comment: @SimonZhu Yes, I've solved it.